# Can the id and a class have the same name of an html element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, naming-conventions, custom-selectors

The CSS allows that I can have a class called “.header”, as well as “.main”, “.footer”, “.aside” and so on... the same for IDs. In theory, I can have 3 selectors with almost the “same” name, like “article”, “.article” and “#article”. And I can do the same with all elements, including, why not, a class called “.html” and an ID called “#body”, etc.

For me, if I see the DOT I know that is a class, and if I see the HASH, I know that is an ID, so for me no confusions, but does it go against the naming conventions?

Comment: As you already know, it's valid. In fact, the HTML5 sectioning elements like article, section, header etc were chosen _because_ they were commonly used class names. There's no canonical naming convention, so in general there's nothing to go against. Of course, they might violate a _specific_ naming convention, but that only matters if it's the specific naming convention that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you absolutely can. If you’re the only one working on the project, and if this is intuitive to you, go right ahead, no issues.

But when working with a larger team, it generally makes sense to use ids and classes that are little more descriptive in nature. For example, `.left-primary-sidebar` would tell me a whole lot more about the element than something like `.aside`, when going through the stylesheet.

Your naming choices are definitely *valid*.

Naming conventions can differ from company to company, so if you’re the only one working on the repo, you can set your own conventions.